# SugarCRM initial_filter fail when the account name is having " in it

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am very new to sugarCRM 6.5.

I have a question in sugarCRM we have initial filter which is working fine if the account name is not having any " in it. but when there is " available in the account name the quick search popup is not opening.

eg: if the account name is "CK" D. Pharma then the quick search is not opening the popup.

For this in the console error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at index.php:1036:1)"

when I click on the index.php it show

```
SUGAR.util.doWhen(
        "typeof(sqs_objects) != 'undefined' && typeof(sqs_objects['EditView_osict_memberpalmoil_contacts_name']) != 'undefined'",
        enableQS
);
```

A x (cross mark) near SUGAR.util.doWhen(**x**

I don't know what to do now, please help me out here.

Please let me know if any additional info is required.

Thanks in advance.